# Is it OK to remove superfluous tags?

Tags: discussion, moderation

When a question is tagged, and deals, with a very specific technology/genre/framework, that is within a larger framework/tech scope that the question is also tagged with, is it socially acceptable to remove the "parent" tag?

For example, I'm a Java person.  Java encompasses quite a few "technologies;" Spring, Struts, Ruby, etc etc.  I constantly run into question that are completely isolated to a framework but are also tagged as `java`.  Here's a few

- [Totally Struts related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481176/use-of-logiciterate-with-string-array).  Nothing to do with Java itself
- [Maven question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481581/how-to-generate-a-dependency-tree-of-a-maven-project-even-if-all-modules-genera) with no Java specific material.
- [Glassfish question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816218/trying-to-run-glassfish-server-on-openshift-in-a-diy-cartridge).

I understand why the person asking would use as many tags as they can think of related to it.  However, as someone looking for questions to answer, I find it annoying to open these types of questions that are tagged `java` only to see they really aren't about Java, they're very specific to one of the other tags.

TL;DR:  Will I get my wrist virtually slapped for removing quasi-related tags from questions?